# Resizing iframe to dynamic content from Chrome extension content script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In my extension, I have a content script that creates a `<div>` containing an `<iframe>` inside the current webpage (e.g. www.google.com). I load a page into the iframe, but the content has to be dynamic, so I post a bunch of HTML to the background page first using `sendRequest`. The iframe page then queries the background page (again with `sendRequest`), gets the HTML and adds it to the page's body.

The issue is that the iframe is not sized correctly when the dynamic content is added, so it has scrollbars. I would like to do something like this:

```
iframe.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    div.style.height = iframe.style.height = iframe.contentDocument.body.scrollHeight;
    div.style.width = iframe.style.width = iframe.contentDocument.body.scrollWidth;
}, false);
```

Unfortunately I have two problems with this. First of all, the `DOMContentLoaded` event is never fired (why?). Secondly, I presumably won't have access to `iframe.contentDocument` anyway since iframe is loading from a different domain.

I could have the iframe use `sendRequest` to post its size somewhere where the hosting page can get its hands on it. However, I am using the same code to insert the iframe into a popup window as well, so there's no easy way to send the request (since it will use `chrome.tabs.sendRequest`for the content script but `chrome.extension.sendRequest` for the popup window).

Any ideas about how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Poked around a bit more and found a solution. The iframe, once it has loaded the dynamic content, calls:

```
var size = { height: document.body.scrollHeight, width: document.body.scrollWidth };
top.postMessage(JSON.stringify(size), "*");
```

The parent window contains:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    var size = JSON.parse(event.data);
    iframe.style.height = div.style.height = size.height + "px";
    iframe.style.width = div.style.width = size.width + "px";
});
```

Comment: Matthew, in `top.postMessage`, is `top` a variable you have assigned, or is it a variable that is automatically available like `parent`?

Comment: `top` is a standard property of `window`.